# How to automatically extract values from matrices

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R, I now have a matrix of 3 columns and 8, 000 rows, with groups of 500 rows, which means 16 sets of 500*3 matrices stacked on top of each other in rows. Now I want to take the first 300 rows of each group of matrices, put 16 groups of 300 by 3 into a new matrix, what do I do?

Comment: First step: transform your matrix into an array of dimensions 500 * 3 * 16. Then this becomes a simple exercise in array subsetting.

Comment: do you mean like this? `new_m <- m[rep(c(rep(T,300), rep(F,200)), 16),]` where `m` is your matrix and `new_m` is the new matrix (4800x3)

Answer (score 1):

Two 6 * 2 matrices on top of each other:

```
m <- matrix(1:24, ncol = 2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   13
# [2,]    2   14
# [3,]    3   15
# [4,]    4   16
# [5,]    5   17
# [6,]    6   18
# [7,]    7   19
# [8,]    8   20
# [9,]    9   21
#[10,]   10   22
#[11,]   11   23
#[12,]   12   24
```

Make it an array:

```
a <- array(m, c(6, 2, 2))
a <- aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2))
```

First three rows of each matrix:

```
a[1:3,,]
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   13
#[2,]    2   14
#[3,]    3   15
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7   19
#[2,]    8   20
#[3,]    9   21
```

Use this if you need a matrix:

```
matrix(aperm(a[1:3,,], c(1, 3, 2)), ncol = 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   13
#[2,]    2   14
#[3,]    3   15
#[4,]    7   19
#[5,]    8   20
#[6,]    9   21
```

Comment: thank you very much. But I still not understand the "aperm ()", What does that mean the vector: c(1,3,2), I searched some information on the Internet to express the meaning of dimensional transformation, but the explanation is not very clear. Could you please explain it in detail? Because my actual matrix is 6 times 8000, and every 500 rows are divided into 16 groups, I don't know how this transformation works, so I can't apply it.

Comment: @WHB533 `aperm` is a generalization of matrix transpose to arrays. `t(m)` switches the first and second dimension of a matrix. You can do exactly the same with `aperm(m, c(2, 1))`. And, e.g., `aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2)` switches the second and third dimension of a 3D array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the sequence 1:300, 501:800, ... etc, then subset out these rows. If your matrix is called `mat` you can do that like this:

```r
new_mat <- mat[as.numeric(sapply((0:15 * 500), "+", 1:300)),]
```

Comment: I can't find which bag this function is in, please tell me which bag has “mat” function

Comment: `mat` is not a function. It is the name of your matrix. You didn't tell us the name of your matrix, so I had to make one up! That's why I said "If your matrix is called `mat`". That means you change `mat` in the answer to whatever your own matrix is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just a way to select the first 300 rows from your matrix for each group, this could be a solution.

Given `m` your matrix of 8000x3 composed by 16 groups on top of each other, then:

```
r <- 500 # rows for each group
g <- 16  # number of groups
n <- 300 # first n rows to select

new_m <- m[rep(rep(c(T,F), c(n,r-n)), g), ]
dim(new_m)
#> [1] 4800    3
```

`new_m` is now a matrix 4800x3

---

In case you are working with `keras` or `reticulate`, you could use `array_reshape`.

```r
#### 0. parameters
nrows <- 4 # 500 in your example # rows for each group
ncols <- 3 #   3 in your example
ngrps <- 2 #  16 in your example # number of groups
nslct <- 3 # 300 in your example # first n rows to select


#### 1. create an example matrix
m <- matrix(1:24, nrows*ngrps, ncols)
m 
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    9   17
#> [2,]    2   10   18
#> [3,]    3   11   19
#> [4,]    4   12   20
#> [5,]    5   13   21
#> [6,]    6   14   22
#> [7,]    7   15   23
#> [8,]    8   16   24
dim(m) 
#> [1] 8 3
#--> c(ngrps * nrows, ncols)


#### 2. reshape in groups
m <- reticulate::array_reshape(m, c(ngrps,nrows,ncols))
dim(m)
#> [1] 2 4 3
# --> c(n_groups, n_rows, n_cols)

m[1,,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    9   17
#> [2,]    2   10   18
#> [3,]    3   11   19
#> [4,]    4   12   20
m[2,,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    5   13   21
#> [2,]    6   14   22
#> [3,]    7   15   23
#> [4,]    8   16   24


#### 3. select first nslct rows for each group
new_m <- m[,seq_len(nslct),]

# that's the result for each group
new_m[1,,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    9   17
#> [2,]    2   10   18
#> [3,]    3   11   19
new_m[2,,]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    5   13   21
#> [2,]    6   14   22
#> [3,]    7   15   23


#### 4. recreate one matrix
reticulate::array_reshape(new_m, c(nslct*ngrps,ncols))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    9   17
#> [2,]    2   10   18
#> [3,]    3   11   19
#> [4,]    5   13   21
#> [5,]    6   14   22
#> [6,]    7   15   23
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to generate an array that mimics the fill of your matrix is to use the transpose of the matrix as the input for the array function.  Here is a simple example:

```
n <- rep(1:3, each = 4)
m1 <- matrix(n, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
> m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    2    2
[5,]    3    3
[6,]    3    3
m2 <- t(m1)
a1 <- array(m2, c(2, 2, 3))
> a1
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3
```